NavigationLink does not link to views in Swift iOS
NavigationLink does not link to views is using foreach with NavigationLink. What is the solution for it to work properly.
NavigationView(){
            ZStack(){
                Color(.systemGray6).ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack()
                {
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)
                    {
                        HStack()
                        {
                            ForEach(MockData.items)
                            { item in
                                
                                ZStack
                                {
                                    Button(action:{ })
                                    {
                                        
                                        NavigationLink( destination: selectedView(name: item.name))
                                        {EmptyView()}
                                        
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                            .foregroundStyle(item.color.self)
                                            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                                    }
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: item.image)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                                        .padding(25)
                                }
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                        }//scrollview
                        
                        //opciones
                    }//cierre del VStack
                    
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    Spacer()
                    
                }//cierre Zstack
                
            } //cierre de Zstack
            .navigationTitle("Caracteristicas")
            
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading)
                {
                    Button(action:{},
                           label: {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "switch.2")})
                    
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing)
                {
                    Button(action:{},
                           label: {Image(systemName: "person.circle")})
                }
                
            }//toolBar
            
            .accentColor(.red)
            
        }
    }
    
}
    
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
                    
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var color: Color
        var image: String
                   
        }
    
@ViewBuilder
private func selectedView (name: String) -> some View {
            
            switch name {
                
            case "Medical": MedicalView()
            case "Illness": IllnessView()
            case "Vaccune": VaccuneView()
            case "Dewor":  DeworView()
            case "Allergie": AllergieView()
                
            default: EmptyView()
                
                
            }
        }

struct MockData {
    static var items = [Item(name: "Medical" ,color: .red, image:"heart"),
                        Item(name: "Illnes" ,color: .blue, image:"pill"),
                        Item( name:"Vaccune" ,color: .orange, image: "syringe"),
                        Item(name: "Dewor" ,color: .green, image: "microbe"),
                        Item(name: "Allergie" ,color:.purple, image: "allergens")]
    
}


You pass EmptyView() as the destination for your NavigationLink so NavigationStack doesn't know where to navigate because the view you supplied as the destination is, well, empty.
A solution would be the following for example:
NavigationLink {
    selectedView(name: item.name)
} label: {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .foregroundStyle(item.color.self)
            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
        Image(systemName: item.image)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .padding(25)
    }
}

The first closure provides the destination of the NavigationLink, the second closure the view that is rendered as the tappable link
